# How can i control volume for specific application?

Tags: c++, winapi, volume

I'm about writing code in C++ which i can use to control volume (for example, Google chrome), I added that function to my code, but it control master volume instead of just the application volume:

```
setChangeVolume(const double & iVolume)
  {
      HRESULT hr=NULL;
      double newVolume = iVolume;

      CoInitialize(NULL);
      IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
      hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
          __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&deviceEnumerator);
      IMMDevice *defaultDevice = NULL;

      hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &defaultDevice);
      deviceEnumerator->Release();
      deviceEnumerator = NULL;

      IAudioEndpointVolume *endpointVolume = NULL;
      hr = defaultDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), 
          CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, (LPVOID *)&endpointVolume);
      defaultDevice->Release();
      defaultDevice = NULL;

      // -------------------------
      float currentVolume = 0;
      unsigned int icurrentVolume = 0;
      endpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevel(&currentVolume);

      hr = endpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(&currentVolume);
      hr = endpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(static_cast<float>(newVolume), NULL);

      endpointVolume->Release();

      CoUninitialize();
}
```

Do you have anyidea how to that and if it's possible ? 
Thanks